# Microphone does not work on Asus VivoBook X202E

Tags: asus, microphone

I have recently bought an Asus Vivobook X202E, with touch screen and Windows 8. I have tried to adjust the sound systems as many answers on this site suggest, but it still doesn't work.

I think Asus X202E has it typical driver requirement or typical problem that can not be solved as the other notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with microphone in Ubuntu 14.04 LTE on my ASUS Vivobook X202E too.

Here where I found the solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203855&p=13084887#post13084887

What you need to do is:

- run `alsamixer` in terminal
- press in `F4` in AlsaMixer to switch to **Capture** tab
- using left/right arrows choose **Mic Boost** control
- using `q` key set left part of **Mic Boost** bar to 100%, using `c` key set right part to 0
- using up/down keys set **Capture** bar to 100 (both for R and L)

That's it.